# Are transactions validated by anchors, and how are they rewarded?

Tags: token, anchor

We have created our own custom token which is currently running on TestNet but will go on to production soon. I have a few questions:

- Is an anchor specific for a token? Is it true that an anchor for *X Token* cannot validate transactions for a different token?
- I see that there are many Stellar-based tokens on https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/. When a transaction of one such token is validated to be recorded on the stellar blockchain, the validation is done by anchors, correct?
- To validate the transaction, how are the anchors rewarded?

Answer (score 3):

Nobody is rewarded for validating transactions. All transactions are equal, regardless of the assets involved. Anchors do not validate transactions. Validation is done by validating nodes. People decide to run a validating node if they obtain [business advantages from doing so](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html#why-run-a-node).

Anchors are entities (accounts) that bridge off-network value to tokens representing that value (assets). For example:

- [Stronghold is an anchor for BTC](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/BTC-GBSTRH4QOTWNSVA6E4HFERETX4ZLSR3CIUBLK7AXYII277PFJC4BBYOG). This means the Stronghold organisation has an account that produces tokens that Stronghold will issue when they receive Bitcoin.
- [Cryptomover is an anchor for Hong Kong Dollars](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/HKDT-GABSZVZBYEO5F4V5LZKV7GR4SAJ5IKJGGOF43BIN42FNDUG7QPH6IMRQ).
- [The White Company is anchor for an asset called WSD](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/WSD-GDSVWEA7XV6M5XNLODVTPCGMAJTNBLZBXOFNQD3BNPNYALEYBNT6CE2V), which they say is redeemable for US Dollars.

etc.

You can issue any asset you like. One of the goals of the network's SDEX is to enable payments with anything of value that has been tokenized.

Lumenauts has a good, short [overview of assets and anchors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf9CdFVse-w).